# What is the order of elements when we iterate using for-each construct in collections?

Tags: java, collections, foreach

When we iterate collections using `for each` construct, what is the logic java uses to pick each element from the collection at each iteration, is that random or a some kind of defined sort? Or is that associated with *natural ordering*?

```
for(Student student:students){
  System.out.println(student);
}
```

Comment: Depends on the collection really. If its a `list` then it is order of insertion. What type of collection is `students`?

Comment: This loop uses the `Iterable` nature of the collection, which uses its underlying `Iterator` , so it all depends on how the iterator is implemented for the given collection.  e.g for `List` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator--

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant

```
for (Student student:students)
```

the iteration order is determined by the `Iterable`'s implementation of the type of `students` (unless `students` is an array, in which case the order is well defined).

Examples:

For `List`s, the order is well defined.

For general `Set`s it is not (though some `Set`s such as `TreeSet` do have order).

> or is that associated with natural ordering

Sometimes it is. If you are iterating over a `TreeSet` whose element type implements `Comparable`, the the order will be the natural ordering of the element type (assuming you didn't pass a `Comparator` defining different ordering to the `TreeSet`'s constructor).

Answer (score 2):

It is based on what type of collection you are using

```
for(Student student:students){
 System.out.println(student.toString());
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (Iterator<String> i = students.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
{ 
    Student student= i.next(); 
    System.out.println(student.toString()); 
}
```

`i.next()` gets the next student object and its(`next()` method) implementation is based on collection type.

It might be in the same order as in the memory.

Read more: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-does-enhanced-for-loop-works-in-java.html#ixzz5X0Wf0Eak